# Discord js: How would i get an array of all members in a server?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need to get a list of all the members in a server.
I tried

```
client.guilds.cache.get(message.guild.id).members.cache.array()
```

but for some reason, it only returned 2 users: me, and the bot, despite the fact that there are more than 2 members of my server.
Is this the correct way of getting the users, and should this code work?

Comment: Most likely because the rest of the members are not in cache and/or you have to enable GuildMember Intents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this when declaring client

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ ws: { intents: [ 'GUILD_MEMBERS'] }});
```

Then turn on gateway intents in [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Then look for gateway intents

[image: It should look like this after turning on intents]

**Note: Once you hit 100 servers it'll need whitelisting and some time to be approved / verified by Discord(Mine took about 3 months)**

Comment: Adding that for some reason broke my bot.... as soon as i removed the "{ws: {intents: ['GUILD_MEMBERS']}, it started working again.

Comment: Edit: adding the "GUILD" intent fixed it.